# Psychological effects of a deep blue sky?

Tags: psychology

Would a deeper shade of blue affect our mood at all?

Comment: No. not even...... For millennia humanity never noticed the color blue at all or they simply ignored it, and some studies  say humans couldn't even see the color blue back then.

Comment: @άλεξμιζέρια "couldn't even see the color" - really? Do you mean studies based on language not having words for blue? Because that has nothing to do with not seeing the color, it is a matter of categorization and linguistics.

Comment: @άλεξμιζέρια, the idea that studies have shown that certain tribes now or people at some point in the past "couldn't see blue" because they don't or didn't have a specific term for it has been pretty thoroughly debunked. For instance see [here](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=18237). In one widely quoted experiment lack of a specific term for blue seemed to slightly slow down reaction times for colour identification for some people from the Himba tribe. This was wildly exaggerated by the BBC and other news sources.

Comment: The sky gets a pretty deep blue everyday before it goes black. And I'm still singing Everything is Awesome along with my friends.

Answer (score 3):

That is unlikely. If the sky had always been a different color we would have evolved to react to the differently colored sky in the same way we react to the current sky.

Answer (score 3):

In this article I found about [Room Color and How it Affects Your Mood](http://freshome.com/room-color-and-how-it-affects-your-mood/), it says

> Blue is known to have a calming effect when used as the main color of a room — but go for softer shades. Dark blue has the opposite effect, evoking feelings of sadness.

From experience, this makes sense, it seems like people become sad more often at night, when the sky is 'midnight blue'. Also, there's pretty good evidence that a lack of natural sunlight has negative effects on humans, so if your sky is a deeper, darker blue, people might not be getting as much sun as they would normally.

So in general, a deeper blue sky may lead to higher levels of sadness and depression. However, the causes behind humans' reactions to colors is not fully understood. If the theory of [evolutionary aesthetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_aesthetics#Landscape_and_other_visual_arts_preferences) is to be believed, humans should respond differently to different colors based on evolution and natural selection, which would mean that humans from Earth should experience the effects described above. However, experience may also play a role in our reactions to colors, and so these effects may not be found (or found to a lesser degree) to humans who have never lived under a light-blue-colored sky. Similarly, humans who evolved under a deep blue sky should also respond to it in much the same way we respond to our own sky.

Comment: This assumes that the reason we find deeper blue more depressing is independent of living in a place with a light blue sky - any reasons for this assumption?

Comment: @rumtscho I'm assuming that the psychological responses to colors are primarily evolutionary, and that we're talking about Earth-bred humans here. I suppose you're right, they could be learned responses, in which case this would probably not be the right answer. I'll see if I can find anything that indicates as much.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know why, but I interpreted the question as "if the sky had always been darker blue". If it means "if the sky suddenly turns dark blue", then your answer makes sense. If it is the first case, no idea if it is true or not, or how it could be tested at all.

Comment: @rumtscho I tried to add some extra detail to make my assumptions clear. If the OP decides they want what you were thinking instead of what I was thinking, I'll edit or delete this answer as needed.